# Set Layoutparameter to xamarin dialog

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

Hello i am developing one app where i want to display dialog in it and i displayed dialog but it display very small.

I want to display custom dialog to fit window screen and height according to the content

here is my code

```
 Dialog dd = new Dialog(this.Activity);
             dd.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.addalbum);

             dd.Show();
```

i want to display dialog at center with width=match_parent and height=wrap_content

i found some code but it is from android

```
 WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            lp.copyFrom(dialog2.getWindow().getAttributes());
            lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            dialog2.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

i want to to set params just like android in xamarin

Please solve this problem